# Export MP3 file with JAR file using JLayer (JZoom) API

Tags: java, jar

I am using the JLayer(JZoom) API to play an mp3 file in my java application.

This is the code I implemented, I created a method and then call it later which works fine:

```
public void playMusic() {
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myfilepath/file.mp3");
            Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);
            playMP3.play();
        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to play the file.");
        }
    }
```

When I export a runnable JAR file, the file is not included. I have also included the MP3 file in an assets folder located in the SRC folder of my application.

What can I do different in order to include the MP3 file when exporting to a runnable JAR file ?

Comment: Use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("myfilepath/file.mp3")` to load the resource from within the Jar file

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot use a `FileInputStream`* to load a resource from a JAR file, because a resource in a JAR file is not a file.

Use:

```
InputStream in = YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myfilepath/file.mp3");
```

assuming the path inside the JAR file is `myfilepath/file.mp3`, and `YourClassName` is the name of any class inside the JAR file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however when I implemet your solution the following error is thrown: java.lang.NullPointerException: in
 at javazoom.jl.decoder.Bitstream.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: @mario.borg Was `in` null? If so, then the path is wrong.

Comment: Yes in is null. I am putting the file in asset folder in the SRC folder and stating the full path. Can you suggest the best way to place the MP3 file.

Comment: @mario.borg Where is the resource *in the JAR*? It doesn't care where it came from. If you don't know, open the JAR in 7-Zip or WinRAR and find out.

Comment: Funnily enough the MP3 is not being added in the JAR file. How Can I ensure that this is being added ?